# How to set a label text of a form using the value of a textbox of another form?

Tags: vb.net

I have three form login.vb, dashbord.vb and stock.vb
In the login.vb form I use this
`Public LoginUser As String`

and in login button use this
`LoginUser = txtUser.Text`

then I use the LoginUser in a label of the dashbord.vb form

```
Private Sub Dashbord_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        hi.Text = My.Forms.login.LoginUser
End Sub
```

after that, I use again the LoginUser in a label of the stock.vb form

```
 Private Sub Stock_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Label1.Text = My.Forms.login.LoginUser
    End Sub
```

After that when I run the program hi.text of the dashbord.vb form shows the value of LoginUser of Login.vb form
But Label1.Text of the stock.vb form didn't show the value of LoginUser of Login.vb form

Comment: try setting it to the `hi.text` if that is what form loads after the login form, so `Label1.Text =   dashboard.hi.Text`

Comment: Might not work but other than that From what you provided I cant see anything that could be causing the problem. How are you opening/closing the other forms after login etc.

Comment: Assign the value to the Field of a Module. You cannot keep a Form open just to read a string. If the Fom is closed, you create a new instance of it, which will give you back an empty string.

Comment: Thank you @Jimi for your advice.

Comment: No problem @AbhiBanik